# Attribute translatable="false" to the root <resources> element?

Tags: android, android-resources

I have some strings of chemical names in a single `values/fertilizers.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="grade_dap">Diammonium phosphate - DAP (18:46:00)</string>
    <string name="grade_ssp">Single super phosphate - SSP (00:16:00)</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

Now since all these strings in this file shouldn't be translated, can I put a single `translatable="false"` attribute to the root `<resources>` element, or do I have to put it for all the individual string elements like so:
`<string name="grade_dap" translatable="false">Single super phosphate - SSP (00:16:00)</string>`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Referring to the [Android Studio Project Site](http://tools.android.com/recent/non-translatablestrings):

> If you have a lot of resources that should not be translated, you can
>   place them in a **file named donottranslate.xml** and lint will consider
>   all of them non-translatable resources.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for. Thank you. :)

Comment: I also read here in StackOverflow that it is possible to use donottranslate as resource prefix, like donottranslate-fertilizers.xml

Answer (score 29):

If you want to use it to avoid lint warnings, you can simply put *MissingTranslation* attribute to cover them all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:ignore="MissingTranslation">

  <string name="grade_dap">Diammonium phosphate - DAP (18:46:00)</string>
  <string name="grade_ssp">Single super phosphate - SSP (00:16:00)</string>
  ...
</resources>
```

Comment: Not a great idea if the file also contains strings that *should* be translated. Warnings about those are quite useful and shouldn't be suppressed.